# Constrain button within a view so that they are all evenly spaced

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, constraints

I'm struggling constraining a set of button (see below), so that they the vertical space between them is equal.  I am trying to create a subview with buttons that mimics a keypad.  I constrain the top center button to the horizontal center and top space to view.  I constrain the bottom center button to the horizontal center and bottom space to view.  How do I get those middle 2 buttons to be evenly spaced?  On android I would accomplish this by using `dp` (density independent pixels), however, if i try to constrain these buttons by vertical spacing, it will be different on every display because the pixel densities are different.

[image]

Comment: why not use collectionViews? It is easier to add logic to your buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you look for a `UIStackView` so , compose your purpose with a set of horizontal stackviews nested inside a vertical stackView , Note this suggest for some items , if you will have too much buttons you can try `UIScrollview/UICollectionView` , key property of stackView that will solve your issue

```
distribution:FillEqually
```